# Call method on parent controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I extend a controller that has a method:

```
show($id){
    //do something
}
```

In my extended controller I override the show method:

```
show($id){
    //do something else
}
```

How can I call the show method on the parent controller?

```
show($id){
    if($id == 1) //go to show method on parent controller
}
```

Comment: call `parent::show();`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
Class BaseController {

    protected function show($id){
        return "Test Succeeded";
    }

}

Class MyController extends BaseController {

    public function show($id){
       if($id == 1){
           parent::show($id);
       }
    }

}

echo (new MyController())->show(1); //Returns Test Succeeded
```